# Python picamera exposure_mode night not working

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, sensor, raspicam

**This program is coded within Python.**

As I wanted to get my raspberry to be aware of the current time(night or day) and being able to upload a video that is using night vision from the normal **cam.exposure_mode = "night"**, my program keeps not filming in night vision some how. I have tried to do this beside python, by command line, and this seems to work with night vision:

```
raspistill -ex night -o test.jpg
```

Would be awesome with some help, of what is going wrong in my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera
import datetime
import subprocess
import dropbox
import os

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'keyHERE'
app_secret = 'secretHERE'

def getFileName():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.h264")

def dropboxAuth():
    accessTokenFileOverwrite = open("accessToken.txt", "w+")

    flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)
    authorize_url = flow.start()

    # Have the user sign in and authorize this token
    authorize_url = flow.start()
    print '1. Go to: ' + authorize_url
    print '2. Click "Allow" (you might have to log in first)'
    print '3. Copy the authorization code.'
    code = raw_input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

    try:
        # This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code
        access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)
        accessTokenFileOverwrite.write(access_token)
    except:
        print "failed authorization, restart"
        accessTokenFileOverwrite.close()
        os.remove("accessToken.txt")

    accessTokenFileOverwrite.close()

def dropboxUpload(fileToUpload):
    if not os.path.isfile("accessToken.txt"):
        dropboxAuth()

    #get access token from file
    accessTokenFileRead = open("accessToken.txt", "r")
    access_token = accessTokenFileRead.read()
    accessTokenFileRead.close()

    # make client
    client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)

    #upload file
    fileToUploadObject = open(fileToUpload, "rb")
    response = client.put_file(fileToUpload, fileToUploadObject)
    fileToUploadObject.close()


sensorPin = 7

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(sensorPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

prevState = False
currState = False

cam = picamera.PiCamera()

currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
nightlight = "18:00"
daylight = "04:45"

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    prevState = currState
    currState = GPIO.input(sensorPin)
    fileName = getFileName()
    if currState != prevState:
        newState = "HIGH" if currState else "LOW"
        print "GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensorPin, newState)
        if currState and currentTime < daylight and currentTime <= daylight:
            print "Starting Recording..."
            print "Time is: "+ currentTime + " meaning we will use night vision!"
            cam.exposure_mode = 'night'
            cam.start_preview()
            cam.start_recording(fileName)
            cam.wait_recording(20)
            dropboxUpload(fileName)
            print (fileName)
        elif currState and currentTime > daylight and currentTime <= nightlight:
            print "Time is: "+ currentTime + " it is still daylight"
            cam.exposure_mode = 'auto'
            cam.start_preview()
            cam.start_recording(fileName)
            cam.wait_recording(20)
            print (fileName)
        else:
            cam.stop_preview()
            cam.stop_recording()
            print "Stopped Recording"
            print "Sending Mail Notification..."
            subprocess.call("mail -s 'Motion Detected!' sample@email.com < /home/pi/message.txt", shell=True)
            print "Complete"
            print "Uploading footage to Dropbox..."
            #dropboxUpload(fileName)
            print "Complete"
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you get an error message? if so what?  Do you get a video file? if so what's wrong with it?

Comment: There is no error, the only thing I see on the video is that it does not use the "exposure_mode = 'night' " - this means that it will never record in night mode, but treat the video as day light. So the only failure I get is that exposure_mode is not working as expected.

Comment: And you get "...we will use night vision" as expected?

Answer (score 1):

`if currState and currentTime < daylight and currentTime <= daylight`  is probably your problem.  I suspect you mean `if currState and currentTime <= daylight or currentTime > nightlight`.  If you're testing in the evening you'd never trigger the nightlight setting with your conditional.

Comment: I will get back to you to check if this works when I get home. But that does still not resolve the exposure_mode = "night" function for the video to record in night ( meaning night vision - because I have a camera that supports that ).

Comment: Do you mean that a very simple python program with no conditionals still won't do night mode? (should be around 6 lines I think, I don't have a PiCam here)

Comment: Yes that is true. I cannot get it working with that code I wrote above. Please let me know if you find a solution.